# How can I keep the same IP address for one machine in my network?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I have several machines at my home and most of them are wireless. My desktop and my network drive are plugged in to my router directly. I would like those two items to always have the same ip how can I ensure this. My desktop (MAC) is running a website that I need to test from my Laptop (PC)

**WORKING ???**
so I think I have things setup right but I'm not sure, so I have the router setup like this

[image]

and then I have my network settings like so

[image]

will this work properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either set a static IP and exclude these from the DHCP pool, or simply (and probably easiest), set up DHCP Reservations/static leases.

It changes based on whatever router you have, but usually it involves going to the DHCP configuration and there should be a page that states reservations - simply look at the MAC address of the current machine and set it.

If you need any help on this stage, please give the model of your router and I will try to help you further.

Comment: ok I set it manually but from you said I need to exclude it from the pool. if I "set up DHCP Reservations/static leases."  does that mean that I have to setup that up for every new computer / device that enters my network ? I'm not familiar with this . I have a linksys router

Comment: @mcgrailm, No, you reserve two static IP's for your 2 computers and the router will always give them those 2 IP's.  Everything else that connects will behave normally and receive a dynamic IP.  Not every Linksys router supports this; what is your model#?  Also, the static assignment is actually per MAC address, not computer.  So if you assign your wired NIC MAC to an IP, you'll have to create a separate entry for you wireless NIC MAC.

Comment: @mcgrailm: In short, you'll have to do a setup for every new computer / device that enters your network that will have a static IP.  There is no getting around it.  If you need more information on how to do that, please ask in a new question.

Comment: @Chris Ting I won't need static ip for every machine/device so thats fine. The router model is a WRT54g2 v1 I set it up a long time ago

Comment: @mcgrailm, your stock firmware doesn't support static leases, AFAIK.  It can, however, be flashed with a custom firmware like DD-WRT which does have this feature.

Comment: @mcgrailm, BTW, the "MAC" Wil and I refer to is the [Media Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Access_Control) address identifier for your network card(s), not your Macintosh.

Comment: is it conceivable that some routers will just show a list of mac -> IP but not allow editing? I ask because I can see this list under DHCP but I can't figure out how to edit it and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong because the UI is chinese-only and there's a button there that I can press but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to to do this:

1. Assign them static IP addresses based on their MAC addresses via your router's configuration. (If you can say which router you have, I can probably link you to documentation about how to do it.)
2. Request an IP via the Network settings of the computers themselves (although it won't be possible if another computer on the network has already been assigned that IP by the DHCP server in the router.)

To do it the second way on the Mac (OS 10.6), go to **System Preferences** > **Network**

[image: Mac - System Preferences - Network]

Then select the connection method on the left you're using (eg. Airport) and click Advanced. Then go to the TCP/IP tab and select DHCP with manual IP address and enter the IP that you want.

[image: Mac TCP/IP]

---

For the PC, [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) will show you how depending on which version of Windows you have installed.